# How to toggle between Euro and Procent in kendo grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid, like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SDB.Models.NettoVergelijking.Dienstverband>()
        .Name("overzicht-grid")
        .AutoBind(false)
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(d => d.Naam).Title("Medewerker").ClientTemplate("<span title='${Naam}'>${Naam}</span>").Width(300)
                .Filterable(f =>
                {
                    f.Extra(false);
                    f.Operators(op =>
                    {
                        op.ForString(str =>
                        {
                            str.Clear().Contains("Bevat");
                        });
                    });
                });
            columns.Bound(d => d.Contractvorm).Title("Contractvorm").ClientTemplate("<span title='${Contractvorm}'>${Contractvorm}</span>").Width(200).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true)); ;
            columns.Bound(d => d.Run1.Netto).Title("Periode 1").Filterable(true).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).Width(220).ClientTemplate("# if (Run1.Netto != 0) { #  #= kendo.toString(Run1.Netto, 'n2') #  # } #").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
            columns.Bound(d => d.Run2.Netto).Title("Periode 2").Filterable(true).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).Width(220).ClientTemplate("# if (Run2.Netto != 0) { #  #= kendo.toString(Run2.Netto, 'n2') #  # } #").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
            columns.Bound(d => d.Verschil).Filterable(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;", @class = "NettoVergelijkingVerschil" }).ClientTemplate("# if (Verschil != 0) { #  #= kendo.toString(Verschil, 'n2') #  # } else { # 0,00  # } #").Width(165).Format("{0:#.00}").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
        })
        .Filterable(f => f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new List<object> { 25, 50, 100, 200, 500 }))
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("overzicht-grid-details")
        .Excel(e => e.AllPages(true))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(50)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(d => d.Id);
                model.Field(f => f.Naam);
                model.Field(f => f.Contractvorm);
                model.Field(f => f.Run1.Netto);
                model.Field(f => f.Run2.Netto);
            })
            .Read(r => r.Action("GetOverzicht", "NettoVergelijking").Data("getData"))
            .Sort(d => d.Add(a => a.Verschil).Descending())
        )
)
```

and I have a switch toggle button, like this:

```
    $("#euro-switch").kendoMobileSwitch({
        onLabel: "%",
        offLabel: "€",
        change: function (e) {

            var label = e.sender.value() ? e.sender.options.onLabel : e.sender.options.offLabel.toString();
            var inpbox = $('#SignalThreshold').data("kendoNumericTextBox");
            console.log(inpbox)
            inpbox.setOptions(
                {
                    format: "\\" + label + "\\ #",
                    decimals: 3
                });
            inpbox.value(inpbox.value());
        }

    });
```

So you can toggle between euro and procent.

I have a class like this:

```
public class Overzicht
    {
        [XmlArrayItem("Dvb")]
        public List<Dienstverband> Dienstverbanden { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dienstverband
    {


        [XmlAttribute("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Naam { get; set; }

        public string Contractvorm { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Run1")]
        public RunGegevens Run1 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Run2")]
        public RunGegevens Run2 { get; set; }



        public decimal Verschil
        {
            get
            {
                {

                    return Run1.Netto - Run2.Netto;
                }
            }
        }


        public decimal VerschilPercentage
        {
            get
            {
                return Run1.Netto == 0 ? 0 : ((Run1.Netto - Run2.Netto)/Run1.Netto)*100;
            }
        }
    }

    public class RunGegevens
    {
        public decimal Netto { get; set; }
        public decimal Herr { get; set; }
    }
```

you see a method:

verschil and verschilPercentage. So now I want to toggle between the methods Verschil and VerschilPercentage. So that the user can see the amount in Euro's but can also change the view in percentage.

But how to do this?

Thank you

So how to switch in the grid between: `d.Verschil` and `d.VerschilPercentage`?

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
$("#euro-switch").kendoMobileSwitch({

            onLabel: "%",
            offLabel: "€",
            change: function (e) {

                var label = e.sender.value() ? e.sender.options.onLabel : e.sender.options.offLabel.toString();                        
                var grid = $("#overzicht-grid").data("kendoGrid");               

                if (e.checked) {
                    grid.hideColumn("Verschil");
                    grid.showColumn("VerschilPercentage");
                }
                else {
                    grid.hideColumn("VerschilPercentage");
                    grid.showColumn("Verschil");
                }            

                var inpbox = $('#SignalThreshold').data("kendoNumericTextBox");               
                inpbox.setOptions(
                    {
                        format: "\\" + label + "\\ #",
                        decimals: 2
                    });
                inpbox.value(inpbox.value());
            }

        });
```

But the ProcentVerschil column will not be visible

Comment: I knew that question sounded familiar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621075/kendo-switch-button-in-asp-net-mvc Is that a colleague of yours?

Comment: But that is a other quesion. This is in the grid. So how to switch between two properties? Thank you

Comment: But do you have a solution? Thank you

Comment: What about this suggestion: Extend the Grid to hold both columns, the Currency AND the Percentage. You could set one of them to be hidden initially (very simple, `.Visible(false)` at column setup). It's also very easy to [hide a column](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/hidecolumn) on Button click and [show the other one](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/showcolumn)

Comment: oke, but can you give an example in the code I have sent

Comment: 1) Is it `ProcentVerschil` or `VerschilPercentage`? Ensure you're using the right spelling. 2) Is the column displayed when the Attribute `Visible(false)` is removed? 3) You could try to replace `grid.hideColumn` and `grid.showColumn` with the column indexes, e.g. instead of `grid.hideColumn("Verschil");`it is `grid.hideColumn(4);` and the other Index is 5 probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate both columns but display only one at a time.

1) Update Grid View, add Column (adjust if necessary):

```
columns.Bound(d => d.VerschilPercentage).Hidden().Filterable(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;", @class = "NettoVergelijkingVerschil" }).ClientTemplate("# if (VerschilPercentage != 0) { #  #= kendo.toString(VerschilPercentage, 'n2') #  # } else { # 0,00  # } #").Width(165).Format("{0:#.00}").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
```

2) Update Change handler of switch:

```
change: function (e) {
    // Whatever the other bits do... probably keep them, and add:

    var grid = $("#overzicht-grid").data("kendoGrid");

    if (e.checked) {
        grid.hideColumn("Verschil");
        grid.showColumn("VerschilPercentage");
    }
    else {
        grid.hideColumn("VerschilPercentage");
        grid.showColumn("Verschil");
    }
}
```

Untested of course.

#### UPDATE

Tested with [Kendo Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OMABu)

Comment: Ah, I;v got it . nice

Comment: @thecodeEngine well I can prove that is basically works with this [Kendo Dojo snippet](https://dojo.telerik.com/OMABu). Run it and see yourself. I can't tell you what's wrong in your specific scenario, you probably missed something.

Comment: Yes, But if I click on the switch I get undefined back

Comment: So maybe you try `columns.Bound(d => d.VerschilPercentage).Hidden()` instead of `columns.Bound(d => d.VerschilPercentage).Visible(false)`, i think that's it because I use "hidden" also in Example